# WPF DataGrid columns: how to manage event of value changing

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid

In my WPF C# project, I have a Datagrid as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FixedPositionDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,229,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" Height="128" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="10" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="indice" Binding="{Binding index}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="%" Binding="{Binding percentage}" />                                    
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="DataGridComboBoxColumnAlignment" Header="Allineamento barre" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding alignment}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I need to have an event that manages the value changing in second and third columns (that is "%" and "Allineamento barre"). No need about the value inserted, I just need to raise an event when one of values are changed.
How can I perform it? I need the way to define the event method in which I can define some operations to do.
I've read this [how to raise an event when a value in a cell of a wpf datagrid changes using MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777431/how-to-raise-an-event-when-a-value-in-a-cell-of-a-wpf-datagrid-changes-using-mvv) but I don't have an observable collection linked to datagrid.

EDIT:
The Datagrid ItemSource is linked with the following objects:

```
public class FixedPosition
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int index { get; set; }

    public int percentage { get; set; }
    public HorizontalAlignment alignment { get; set; }        
}
```

How can I modify it to obtain the result expected?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just do what you want in the setter of `percentage` and/or `alignment` property? That's what is triggered when value changes

Comment: @dkozl I need to know how to do it...can you give me an example please?

Comment: Since you can modify `percentage` I assume it has getter `get` and setter `set` so trigger what you want to trigger in the setter which will be whenever `percentage` value has been set: `set { ... [trigger action] }`

Comment: @dkozl I need a clear example...lok at my edit and please give an example based on it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *seem* to be looking at this problem from a WinForms perspective. In WPF, we generally prefer to manipulate data objects rather than UI objects. You said that don't have an `ObservableCollection<T>` for your items, but I would recommend that you use one.

If you don't have a data type class for your data, then I'd advise you to create one.
You should then implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in it.

After doing this and setting your collection property as the `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`, then all you need to do is to attach an `INotifyPropertyChanged` handler to your selected data type:

In the view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); }
}

public YourDataType SelectedItem
{
    get { return selectedItem; }
    set { selectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
}
```

In the view model constructor:

```
SelectedItem.PropertyChanged += SelectedItem_PropertyChanged;
```

In the view model:

```
private void SelectedItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // this will be called when any property value of the SelectedItem object changes
    if (e.PropertyName == "YourPropertyName") DoSomethingHere();
    else if (e.PropertyName == "OtherPropertyName") DoSomethingElse();
}
```

In the UI:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />
```

Comment: I will follow your suggestion and try to use this code. I will let you know

Comment: look at my edit and give me the example of how to change it to obtain the result you have described above to me. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so now you have a data type class: `FixedPosition`. Now you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in it... there are a million tutorials online on how to do this. Once you have done that, look at the first code section in my answer... you need a collection of your `FixedPosition` objects, so add those two properties (from my code), but replace `YourDataType` with `FixedPosition`. Once you've done that, attach a `PropertyChanged` handler to your `SelectedItem` object and then add the properties shown to your `DataGrid`.

Comment: is it the same adding the method DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)?

Comment: No because in the `PropertyChanged` event handler, you get a `PropertyChangedEventArgs` object that tells you which property has changed.

Comment: The problem is that with the configuration described in my question, the value changed is updated in the structure after the event DataGrid_CellEditEnding(). I need that, after changing value, the structure is updated and then the event is raised. Now the structure is automatically updated (I don't do it with some code) using get and set in structure description.