# Get cell id or content of the cell in OnTargetUpdated event of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to data and I have `OnTargetUpdated` implemented. Two cell `variables` and Checkbox `isLive` are read/write. If I change Variables or the CheckBox I bounce into `OnTargetUpdated`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="3" Height="126" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Name="dg_queue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1446" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" ItemsSource="{Binding QueueItems}" TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="30" Binding="{Binding Id, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Submit Time" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Submit_Time, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strategy" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Strategy}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Variables" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Variables, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Live" Width="SizeToHeader" Binding="{Binding Is_Live, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" IsReadOnly="False"/>                
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If I change Variables or the CheckBox I bounce into `OnTargetUpdated` as expected:

```
private void OnTargetUpdated(Object sender, DataTransferEventArgs args)
{
    // Something Changed in the Grid.  
    // if is Is_Live or Variables let's do something useful            
}
```

My question is how do I tell from my sender or my args WHAT I changed (i.e. the CheckBox or the TextBox (variables) or something I don't care about) to trigger the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your task more suitable [`CellEditEnding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

> Occurs before a cell edit is committed or canceled.

Example of using:

**`XAML`**

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CellEditEnding="MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding" ... />
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
private void MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        if (e.Column.Header.Equals("Variables"))
        {
            TextBox textBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
            MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
        }
        else if (e.Column.Header.Equals("IsLive"))
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = e.EditingElement as CheckBox;
            MessageBox.Show(checkBox.IsChecked.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Although it works, I think it looks difficult it is rather a style WinForms, not WPF. In this case, you can keep track of events `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and do something like this:

> Taken from answer: [WPF DataGrid columns: how to manage event of value changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720892/wpf-datagrid-columns-how-to-manage-event-of-value-changing)

In the view model constructor:

```
SelectedItem.PropertyChanged += SelectedItem_PropertyChanged;
```

In the view model:

```
private void SelectedItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // this will be called when any property value
    // of the SelectedItem object changes
    if (e.PropertyName == "YourPropertyName") DoSomethingHere();
    else if (e.PropertyName == "OtherPropertyName") DoSomethingElse();
}
```

In the UI:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />
```

Also, I recommend to look quoted answer:

[WPF DataGrid columns: how to manage event of value changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720892/wpf-datagrid-columns-how-to-manage-event-of-value-changing)